# Cloning a DIV with multiple inputs in Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to javascript and I can't seem to figure out this thing which I reckon should be a no-brainer.

I'm using Jquery mobile. I would like to clone a div and update the IDs of the elements in it. This seems to work fine. However, I can't get the cloned select element to work properly. I doesn't seem to work - I can't select anything - after its been cloned. When I call an extra `$('html').trigger('create');` on the page the select elements starts looking 'funny' (probably because it got enhanced a second time) but does works.

I've posted a simplified version of my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/cUBPF/1/

Does anyone have a suggestion for me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not experiencing any problems however I'm just using my desktop.  My first thought is to avoid calling the `$('html').trigger('create');` at all and simply do what you want to within the clone_button click but then again, I'm not really sure what you are doing.

Instead of doing all this, why not output 10 or 20 of these fields and the display:none/display:block them......I assume you will run into less compability issues this way and you really don't want to allow infinite amount of fields....your going to run into browser memory issues which is just going to cause more bugs.

Comment: I've checked the behavior under both Chrome and FF and can reproduce the error (see jsfiddle) in both. To specify the error: when cloning the div I cannot set the value of the cloned select input. I would like to know how I can achieve this by using this approach, because I have a page with a variable number of subforms resulting in a potentially very large number of hidden fields if I would follow your suggestion.

Comment: I did find and 'easy' way to achieve this, so for now I am going with @hendr1x 's solution.